# mysql match against not matching text in brackets

Tags: mysql, match, brackets

I'm trying to use match against to return search results. 
I have a problem though where it's not returning results where the matching text is in brackets. Just getting rid of the brackets isn't an option i'm afraid.

So running the sql fiddle below I would expect it to return two results, not one

```
CREATE TABLE `courses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `course_code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `course_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startdate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `starttimestamp` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospectus_title` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `info` (`course_name`,`prospectus_title`,`course_code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=981074 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `courses` (`id`, `course_code`, `course_name`, `startdate`, `starttimestamp`, `prospectus_title`) VALUES 
('1', '1234', 'vrqtest', 'time','time', 'vrqtest'), 
('2', '5678', '(vrq)test', 'time','time','(vrq)test');

SELECT * FROM courses force index(info) 
WHERE starttimestamp IS NOT NULL AND ( 
MATCH ( course_name ) against ('vrq*' in boolean mode ))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ca6d/1)

That returns only the first record but should also the second.

Any ideas?

Comment: use against in capital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len

> **ft_min_word_len**
>
> The minimum length of the word to be included in a
>   FULLTEXT index. Defaults to 4

(vrq)test is too short to match. Add an extra character (e.g. (vrqa)test ) and it's matched.

Comment: Did you try it in the Fiddle?

Comment: @juergend that won't work. '*' is an operator that works appended. It's not a wildcard per-se